# TypeScript interface for object with language labels

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, label

On my ReactJS app I used to use labels.js objects to switch between languages:

```html
export const labelsENG = {
  navSeries: 'shows',
  navHome: 'home',
  navVideo: 'video',
  navGames: 'games',
  navCurrent: 'current',
  navCatchUp: 'shame pile',
  navCommingSoon: 'comming soon',
  navFinished: 'finished',
  formModalHeader: 'Add new Poster',
  modalNoWiki: 'No wiki for ',
  modalCloseButton: 'CLOSE MODAL',
  modalReleased: 'Relased ',
  modalSeenAt: 'You seen it ',
  itemPart: 'Part ',
  itemSeason: 'Season ',
  footerCopyRights: '© 2022 Listownik by Kuba',
  footerHere: 'Footer here',
  error404: 'Error 404 Page Not Happy',
  errorDescribtion: `It's working anyway`,
  posterText: 'Some text',
  shelfSeen: 'Seen'
};
```

Now I'm trying to convert that code to TypeScript.
Is there any more efficient or elegant way to declare a type for that object than create an interface with strings for each parameter separately?

```html
export interface LabelsInterface {
  navSeries: string;
  navHome: string;
  navVideo: string;
  navGames: string;
  navCurrent: string;
  navCatchUp: string;
  navCommingSoon: string;
  navFinished: string;
  modalNoWiki: string;
  modalCloseButton: string;
  modalReleased: string;
  modalSeenAt: string;
  itemPart: string;
  itemSeason: string;
  footerCopyRights: string;
  footerHere: string;
  error404: string;
  errorDescribtion: string;
  posterText: string;
  shelfSeen: string;
}
```

### Edit

Problem appears when I'm trying to declare type for context labels in next component:

```html
  const { labels }: LabelsInterface = useContext(LanguageContext);
```

**labels** contain labelsENG or labels[someOtherLang]

```html
type Language = {
  lang: string;
  setLang: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Language>>;
};

const initialState: Language = {
  lang: languageLabel.eng,
  setLang: (): void => {}
};

const labelInitialState: {} = {
  labels: {},
  setLang: (): void => {}
};

export const LanguageContext = createContext(labelInitialState);

const DataProvider = () => {
 const [lang, setLang] = useState<Language>(initialState);
 const isLanguageEng: boolean = (lang as any) === 'ENG';
 const labels = isLanguageEng ? labelsENG : labelsPL;
 
 return (
      <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ labels, setLang }}>
        <RouteProvider />
      </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

#### Errors:

```html
TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ navSeries: string; navHome: string; navVideo: string; navGames: string; navCurrent: string; navCatchUp: string; navCommingSoon: string; navFinished: string; formModalHeader: string; modalNoWiki: string; ... 10 more ...; shelfSeen: string; }': navSeries, navHome, navVideo, navGames, and 17 more.

TS2339: Property 'labels' does not exist on type '{ navSeries: string; navHome: string; navVideo: string; navGames: string; navCurrent: string; navCatchUp: string; navCommingSoon: string; navFinished: string; formModalHeader: string; modalNoWiki: string; ... 10 more ...; shelfSeen: string; }'.
```

Comment: Depends what your goal is .. If you have like one master language and what the other ones to follow the same structure you can do  `export type LabelsInterface = typeof labelsENG`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir English are master language in my app. I've got different labels[lang].js files with exactly the same object property names, but a value(string) of that property's in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the constant like you did, just create a new `type` off of that constant, like this: `type LabelTypes = typeof labelsEng`

#### Edit

No `const` as pointed out by Titian in the comments, only `type`. Use `export` if you wish to reuse it.

Comment: No const in front of that type